# Unable to change the size of a view in IB

Tags: xcode

I've just created a xib and dragged a standalone UIView into it, however I am unable to set its size - the X,Y,width, Height  are greyed out within the size inspector.

Yet this is something I have done previous in other projects - and in fact I just opened an older project to check and there I have a standalone UIView in a xib which I am able to size within IB.

Why will IB not permit me to resize this time?

Doing a side by side visual comparison of all the attributes in IB between the view in my new project and the view in my old project I cannot see anything set differently that would account for IB permitting setting the size in one but not in the other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the size to *Freeform* in the Attributes Inspector, under the Simulated Metrics section.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I had previous tried setting it to none, as that is what it is set to in my old project. Yet it didn't work when set to none in the new project, yet that is what it is in the old project!

Comment: This does not always work. For some views there is no size dropdown in the attributes inspector: https://imgur.com/a/Xts1m78