# How to set the size of a view in IB with XCode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode

I already have an answer to this question from a few months ago, however that was applicable for versions of XCode < 5.

[Unable to change the size of a view in IB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066721/unable-to-change-the-size-of-a-view-in-ib)

With XCode 5 there is no longer a simulated metrics section*, so therefore how can you set the size and origin of a view in IB if its dimmed out?

*EDIT - ok so I found out there is still a simulated metrics section with XCode 5, but for me its not showing. (XCode v 5.0). So my question is now why is it not showing?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your view is the main view of a view controller, then you have to change Simulated Metrics properties on the View Controller itself.

If you only want a view though, not a view controller, then get rid of it and insert your view directly in IB, you'll be able to change the simulated metrics properties directly.

Regarding the origin question:
The origin of a view is relative to its superview. If you create your freeform view in a NIB then I guess it's in order to add it to another view later. So you'll have to set the origin dynamically at that precise moment. And you can deal with the iOS6/7 status bar delta at that moment too, programmatically. Otherwise, if you want to do everything in IB, you could also define your freeform view in the NIB of its parent view and add it directly to its parent view, set the origin etc. And then you could maybe use autolayout to deal with the delta, but I'd need to confirm that though.

Comment: No its not there - added new image to posting. So I guess my question is now, where is my simulated metrics section?

Comment: Is your view into a View Controller? If so, you'll have to change the simulated metrics of the view controller itself. Try to tell me a bit more about your view hierarchy so that I can try to reproduce your situation. thanks

Comment: Yes its into a VC? The simulated metrics appears for the VC and if I set it to freeform and status bar to none then go back to the view then I can change the width/height but not the origin. Is it possible to change the origin so I can use ios 6/7 deltas to account for the status bar differences in iOS 6/7?

Comment: I edited my answer, please tell me if it answers your question about the origin because I might have not understand it.

Comment: My question was originally about the origin as I thought the metrics had been removed with XCode 5 as I couldn't find it. Then the question turned into where the metrics had gone, which you had answered, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the answer to the other question you posted, make sure that the status bar style in the Simulated Metrics is None.